# Different URL for homepage then all your other pages

Tags: homepage, home-url

I'm using a theme (in this case woocommerce) but doesnt matter not a theme specific question. And I want to have the homepage on main domain like domain.nl and have all the other pages on product.domain.nl. So all the links/menu links, should be pointing to the subdomain. But the homepage should be on the main domain.

Is there any easy way to do this? And if not what would be the hard way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use multisite. [Enable the WordPress Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and host the home page on the primary site and all the other content on a single subsite (or many subsites).

Answer (score 0):

This plugin hasn't been updated in awhile but check it out [WP Subdomains](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-subdomains/other_notes/)

Comment: Found latest version that works with current WP version but, I doesnt have option to let post have subdomain, only pages. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why on earth would you want your posts to have a subdomain?

Comment: I dont want each post to have a seperate subdomain I want the home URL to be on domain.nl and everything else on product.domain.nl, Why? Because I want one clean pure whitehat, main page targetting main keywords that I want protected from the backhat (just wordspins) i do on my product feeds. Also in the long run I want one shop and have each product in the shop appear on multiple domains all targeting different product longtails